# Decompile Dll - Code has CS$4$0001 for vars

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to edit a dll file if possible or extract the contents and modify them.

I have used .Net Reflector to decompile and generate files.

That worked great except some files have things like `CS$4$0001` instead of variables.

also `<>g__initLocal31`

Is there a way to find what those are? Or Should I just replace all instances, and test?

ADDED:

```
    [OutputCache(NoStore=true, Location=OutputCacheLocation.Client, Duration=1)]
    public ActionResult _StateTile(string AssetName, string StateName)
    {
        aaReportsEntities dataContext;
        string CS$4$0001 = StateName;
        if (CS$4$0001 != null)
        {
            if (!(CS$4$0001 == "IDLE-UPSTREAM"))
```

Comment: Get the source code. Or learn how to reverse engineer.

Comment: I already REed it, I was looking to see if anyone has any tips or different way of doing it. Be useful, don't just post to post. provide links/tuts.

Comment: This is a programmers forum. If you have a question, bring the source code with you. This is an awesome community of friendly, helpful people. This is not a "can't do it, so I'll outsource it to SO, and they'll do it for me" community.

Answer (score 6):

Those can be:

- local variables (don't have names in IL)
- backing fields for automatically implemented properties / field-like events
- fields for anything compiler-generated (capture-context related scopes, etc)
- expression-tree / delegate caches
- "dynamic" caches
- state variables in iterator-blocks / "await" code
- etc (again, mainly anything compiler-generated)

They are important. But frankly, you probably shouldn't be extracting code via reflector: usually, if you have justification in doing that, you already own the source code (or are licensed to access it)

Comment: I'm working on a website for a company. However the creator was not able to find the source code to give to me. So I have to resort to such ways to get at it. I'm not breaking any laws or stealing anyone's code. I think they are Variables.

Answer (score 1):

You cant get variable names back. TReverse engineering is very difficult to do, recommend this book - http://www.amazon.co.uk/Reversing-Secrets-Engineering-Eldad-Eilam/dp/0764574817/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1353436851&sr=8-1

Comment: I'm not even sure I'd call recompiling "reverse engineering", but that is subjective I guess

Comment: By the time i read the book i would have wrote a few dlls... but thanks for reply